# Angular 2 error TS1146: Declaration expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I am an Angular2 rookie so forgive me if this is an obvious mistake. Starting from the angular.io seed files I have been developing a simple app to use Angular Services for the first time. The app seemed working well until I encountered some error which caused Chrome and the npm server to crash. When I attempt to restart the server ('npm start') I receive the following build error -

```
src/app/cost-data.service.ts(5,12): error TS1146: Declaration expected.

npm ERR! Darwin 16.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

The cost-data.service.ts file is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { CostData } from './cost-model';

@Injectable;

export class CostDataService {

costData = new CostData;

}
```

I'd be grateful if someone can tell me the cause of the build error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Injectable;
```

needs to be

```
@Injectable()
```

So your code should look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CostDataService {

costData = new CostData;

}
```

I suggest you to refer to the official Angular documentation and tutorials: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Answer (score 0):

**@Injectable** is the **annotation** which is provided by Angular and all annotations always ends with **()**

So correct code is attached below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { CostData } from './cost-model';

@Injectable()
export class CostDataService {

   costData = new CostData;

}
```